# Add refrrence for custom commands declaration in Cypress.io

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

I added some custom commands to my project and I also added a declaration file. According to [Cypress's documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html#Reference-type-declarations-via-tsconfig), they say `"To include the new ".d.ts" file into IntelliSense, I could update tsconfig.json"`, so I did and I don't know what is wrong...

the `tsconfig` file :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "cypress": [
        "../node_modules"
      ],
      "support": [
        "../support"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "cypress",
      "support"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "config/config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Two things, it could be that the declaration is outside the `path` config object? Also, could you try like so: `"include": ["**/*.*"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

The [cypress/global.d.ts file](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/global.d.ts) demonstrates how to add type declarations for custom commands and tasks and [cypress/tsconfig.json](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tsconfig.json) has additional TypeScript configuration.